# ondragstart event in chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, events, google-chrome-app

In the following code the **ondragstart** event doesn't work in chrome packaged app.
The **onclick** event works fine though.

the browser just ignore this event - no errors or warnings were raised.

How can I use ondragstart, ondrag and ondragend events in chrom apps?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <img id="img1" src="img/add.png" />
    </div>
    <script>
        var image = document.getElementById('img1');

        image.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
        image.addEventListener('dragstart', start, false);

        function onClick(e) {
            console.log('click');
        };

        function start(event) {
            console.log('start');
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it!

I did add `draggable="true"` and everything works fine now.

I think that for some reason chrome sets draggable to false.